# How to deliberately fail a Sphinx build when autodoc fails an import

Tags: python, jenkins, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a CI (Jenkins) job which builds Sphinx documentation for my Python project:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
virtualenv $WORKSPACE
source $WORKSPACE/bin/activate
pip install 'sphinx>=1.3.1'
python setup.py build_sphinx
```

My project uses the Sphinx autodoc extension to extract docstrings from my modules by importing them, e.g. in "docs/api/foo.bar.rst":

```
.. automodule:: foo.bar
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Now, if autodoc fails to import `foo.bar`, the Sphinx build shows the traceback in the logs and carries on building anyway, although it warns me that:

```
WARNING: toctree contains reference to document u'api/foo.bar' that doesn't have a title: no link will be generated
```

This results in missing documentation, so I'd like to make my Sphinx build step fail in this event. Is there a more elegant way of doing this than trying to grep the logs from build_sphinx?

Comment: The [**-W**](http://sphinx-doc.org/invocation.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-W) option makes the build stop at the first warning. It stops at any warning though, not just those triggered by ImportErrors.

Comment: Thanks @mzjn. On further investigation, it doesn't look like the `warningiserror` option exists for the distutils command that does "python setup.py build_sphinx". I've created an issue here for feedback on this: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2039